# How to get git to warn when a merge deletes files

Tags: git, merge

We recently had a problem where a team member accidentally deleted all the new changes that had been applied to the master branch when they merged master into their feature branch, and then when they merged their branch into the master branch all the changes were then deleted. Luckily we caught this early, so it wasn't a big deal, but it still took a day or two to go through and make sure that we didn't lose any work.

The colleague who made the bad merge isn't really sure how it happened, he's done tons of merges before and they've all worked fine and he remembers doing the merge and working through the merge conflicts on that day, so we're not really sure how it happened. He uses TortoiseGit and our best guess is that there was some error or cancellation that backed out all the changes, but somehow left the merge head there and when he made the next commit which he thought was just a normal commit it deleted all the changes.

I did a bit of reading online and understand that when you do a merge commit you're basically telling git "I've manually merged these files, and this is the version of the repository to use from now on", but to me this seems quite dangerous and so **I'm wondering if there is a setting that we could turn on to have git produce a warning when files are deleted in comparison to one of the parents** (especially if they aren't in conflict). If there isn't a setting, is there any reason why such a feature couldn't be implemented in git, am I misunderstanding something? It seems to me like it would be a sensible feature to warn if a file that was changed in one branch is then deleted in the merge.

(Finally I'll mention, we realize that this should've been caught in the pull request review, the problem was that it was a huge PR and this only happened after the initial review, so the reviewer had started just looking at the individual commits rather than the whole PR view, and so it was missed. We've already discussed in the future working to reduce the size of our PRs if we're working on larger features to split them up, but I'm also interested in a more technical solution because there are grumblings on my team about potentially moving away from git if this kind of dangerous action can go uncaught)

(Also, I guess really I'd prefer if it's not just file deletions but any changes that are deleted, so if a number of chunks were changed in one branch, and all those chunks are deleted in the merge, then that would ideally give a warning if there was no conflict to cause them to be deleted)

Comment: You want git to be intelligent and to know if some code changes are correct or not? Doubt this will work and if there is a solution that could help you (at least a bit) I doubt relying on it is a good idea.

Comment: Moving away from Git because of wrong usage by one developer is non-sense, especially as I doubt any other VCS will behave differently. Of course it is in the responsibility of the developer doing the merge to do it correctly. Git also allows the dangerous action to remove all files and commit this, but that does not make it a bad tool, because also this is a valid usage of the tool. Maybe you can devlop a Git hook that does such checks and then prevents the commit or issues a warning.

Comment: I don't want git to know what's correct, but my assumption was that probably 95% of the time during a merge you don't need to edit the files other than what git has identified as a merge conflict, and probably 99% of the time you don't want to delete files that have been added in the other branch, so I thought there might be a way to turn on a warning when you're hitting the minority case. I'll look into a git hook.

Answer (score 0):

merge can be used first with --no-commit option for inspection, and if results are good, final merge can be done..

with --no-commit, you may receive message as below. You can write additional utility , who just grep deletion and warn you.

```
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644
```

Another better option can be to identify well before it comes for merge, just track any commit has any delete file..